# Compare JSON values in MariaDB

Tags: json, mariadb

How can I compare two JSON values in MariaDB? Two values such as `{"b": 1, "a": 2}` and `{"a": 2, "b": 1}` should be equal. Does MariaDB contain function to reorder elements of a JSON value?

Comment: There is an open issue to add `JSON_EQUALS` ([MDEV-23143](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23143)).

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to need this (uncommon) kind of comparison, build the JSON in some canonical way before storing it.  The obvious way for a simple JSON like yours is to alphabetize the keys.  How to do that will depend on the "encode" library you are using for JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just use JSON_EXTRACT, JSON_EXTRACT doesnt care about the position of a digit within a JSON string.

**Query**

```
  SELECT
      JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_1, '$.a') AS a1
    , JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_2, '$.a') AS a2
    , JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_1, '$.b') AS b1
    , JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_2, '$.b') AS b2
  FROM (
    SELECT 
       @json_string_1 := '{"b":1,"a":2}'
     , @json_string_2 := '{"a":2,"b":1}'
  ) 
   AS
    json_strings
```

**Result**

```
a1      a2      b1      b2      
------  ------  ------  --------
2       2       1       1
```

Now use this result as delivered table so we can check if a1 is equal to a2 and b1 is equal to b2.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 1 AS json_equal
FROM ( 

  SELECT
      JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_1, '$.a') AS a1
    , JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_2, '$.a') AS a2
    , JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_1, '$.b') AS b1
    , JSON_EXTRACT(@json_string_2, '$.b') AS b2
  FROM (
    SELECT 
       @json_string_1 := '{"b":1,"a":2}'
     , @json_string_2 := '{"a":2,"b":1}'
  ) 
   AS
    json_strings
) 
 AS json_data
WHERE
   json_data.a1 = json_data.a2
 AND
   json_data.b1 = json_data.b2
```

**Result**

```
json_equal  
------------
           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for MariaDB

See my answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300235/208895 for an example how to use `JSON_EQUALS` available as of 10.7.