# MariaDB - compare two json objects

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

In MySQL 5.7 I can compare two json objects where the order of the key are ignored e.g the following two json string are equal:

```
SELECT CAST('{"num": "27,28", "date": "2019-11-01"}' AS JSON) = CAST('{"date": "2019-11-01", "num": "27,28"}' AS JSON);
```

In mariadb there is no such json data type and so the above will return false.

Is there any way to accomplish the same in mariadb?

Note I've seen the following post and the solution is not ideal: [Compare JSON values in MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734547/compare-json-values-in-mariadb)

Comment: There is an open issue to add `JSON_EQUALS` ([MDEV-23143](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23143)).